# How to get item value in a listview in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have referenced to a tutorial and I have created a custom list view in fragment, but I am unable to get the position or value of any item on item click of list view. I want to show a toast containing the position of the item. I don't know how to implement that.

CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<MyActivityAdapterItem> listData;
    private Context context;

    //private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyActivityAdapterItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
           // holder = new ViewHolder();

            //convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        TextView headingView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView placeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.place);
         TextView reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        headingView.setText(listData.get(position).getHeading());
        placeView.setText("At, " + listData.get(position).getPlace());
        reportedDateView.setText(listData.get(position).getDate());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

FindPeopleFragment.java

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder ;
    ListView lv1;
    ImageButton delall;
    CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[] {"Delete"};
    ArrayList details;
    CustomListAdapter ad1;
    String msg="abc";
    public FindPeopleFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
        delall=(ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.deleteall);
        details = getListData();
        lv1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activitylist);
        ad1=new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), details);
        lv1.setAdapter(ad1);
        builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        delall.setOnClickListener(this);
       lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(MyActivitiesFragment.MSG, msg);
            MyActivitiesFragment f1=new MyActivitiesFragment();
            f1.setArguments(args);
            MainActivity.fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,f1).commit();*/
        }
    });
return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the clicked item in a `ListView` can be retrived easily on the `onItemClick` method as you can see in the documentation:

> public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView parent, View view,
>   int position, long id)
>
> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
>   been clicked.
>
> Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to
>   access the data associated with the selected item.
>
> Parameters parent The AdapterView where the click happened. view  The
>   view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view
>   provided by the adapter) position The position of the view in the
>   adapter. id   The row id of the item that was clicked.

So in your case, the position of the clicked item is the *arg2* value. Your code should be like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), arg2+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /*...*/
}
```

**EDIT:**

To get the Item, you can do like this:

```
(Item) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
```

---

**TL;DR**

You can see in this case that it is important to use good names for parameters. With the default names given by Eclipse - or by others IDEs - this line:

```
(Item) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
```

looks pretty strange. But if you are using the Android names - which gives you `onItemClick(AdapterView<Item> parent, View view, int position, long id)` - the line becomes:

```
(Item) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Which is clearer and easier to use.

Comment: can i store the item value in String,if yes how?

Comment: It depends on what the `ListView` represents. According to your code it mainly contains `TextView`s, is this right? This case you can get the object, collect all the `TextView`s' texts and create a string which is the concatenation of these texts.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected item at position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //   Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Plaeeng.class);
         //   List<ScanResult> wifiList;
         //   i1.putExtra("cuor", );
         //   startActivity(i1);
           Toast.makeText(ListCours.this, "=>"+parent.getAdapter().getItem(position), 5000).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain your code a bit? Why the comments? What is that magic number 5000? Allow others to learn from your answer, not just copy and paste something they don't understand.

Comment: i want to show how to display the value of the listView , The rest of the code belongs to another work. The value  5000 is the duration to show the Toast /// I apologise

Answer (score 0):

You are doing well in setOnItemClickListener
the problem its the autocomplete its not working well in parameters you should have something like this:
 lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

the position is in your arg2, and as a tip you can get the item you click using this snippet:

```
parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```